# mySQL get an example of the the most common item by category

Tags: sql, aggregate, mariadb

I have a table like

```
id category   item
1  candy      bar
2  candy      gum
3  candy      bar
4  candy      gummy
5  candy      cupcake
6  vegetable  carrot
7  vegetable  pea
8  vegetable  pea
9  meat       beef
10 meat       pork
11 meat       chicken
12 meat       chicken
```

I'm tying to build a mysql/maridb query that gives me the total from each category and returns the most common item from each category

```
category     example   total
candy        bar       5
vegetable    pea       3
meat         chicken   4
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `vegetable item` most common be `pea` in your example and not `carrot`?

Comment: Yes.  A typo thanks.  I will fix.

Comment: What if you have a tie?

Comment: Though I see that your sample doesn't have this problem, how do you want to handle ties?

Comment: mariadb supports CTE and some analytical functions mySQL doesn't ... which is this?  Please remove the conflicting RDBMS tag that is not relevant.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0.1 (not yet GA) both support CTEs, in theory.

Comment: just upgraded to MariaDB 10.2 earlier this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT category
         , item
         , count(item) as NumItems
         , dense_rank() over (partition by category order by count(item) desc) as ItemRank
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY category, item)

  SELECT * from CTE WHERE ItemRank = 1
```

Comment: This only shows the NumItems in group.  So I joined the `SELECT * FROM CTE ...` with another subquery `(SELECT category, COUNT(0) AS total FROM table GROUP BY category)` and got the total count.   That provides the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `category` and `total` using a basic aggregation:

```
select i.category, count(*) as total
from items i
group by category;
```

To get the most common item, I would use a correlated subquery with `LIMIT 1` in the SELECT clause:

```
select i.category, count(*) as total, (
    select i1.item
    from items i1
    where i1.category = i.category
    group by i1.item
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
) as example
from items i
group by category;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ICK46600

Note that you might need to add some logic to handle ties. For example - If you want to get the item that occures first, you can change the ORDER BY clause to

```
order by count(*) desc, min(i1.id) asc
```

Comment: Not to correct you, but for the first row returned, wouldn't that give you `cupcake` and not `bar` for the `item`?

Comment: My bad.. I've somehow read "most recent" instead of "most common".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Select a.category, b.item as example, a.total
from

(
Select category, count(*) as total
from Your_Table_Name
GROUP BY category
) a

inner join

(
  Select a.category, a.item, cnt_item from
      (
        SELECT category, item, count(*) as cnt_item
        from Your_Table_Name
        group by category, item
      ) a
  inner join
   (
    Select category,max(cnt_item) as max_rep
    from
        (
        SELECT category, item, count(*) as cnt_item
        from Your_Table_Name
        group by category, item
        ) a
    group by category
   ) b
  on a.category=b.category and a.cnt_item=b.max_rep 
) b
on a.category=b.category;
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc3ac7/1)

Normally I hate selects in select statements; but this gets by a lot of the overhead in coding the subqueries and lack of analytical functions in MySQL and there is a time and place for everything. This seems to be a good use.

```
SELECT A.Category, (SELECT ITEM 
                    FROM TABLE B 
                    WHERE B.Category = A.Category 
                    GROUP BY ITEM 
                    ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, ITEM 
                    LIMIT 1) as Example
     , count(*) as Total
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY A.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT category , item , 
count(item) as NumItems , 
dense_rank() over (partition by category order by count(item) desc) as ItemRank FROM items GROUP BY category, item)

select a.category,item,total from (SELECT * from CTE WHERE ItemRank = 1)a
left join 
(select category, count(*) total
from items
group by category)b
on b.category=a.category
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes a different approach, and uses an efficient [*groupwise-max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .

```
SELECT
    category,
    item AS example, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items1  WHERE category = x.category ) AS total
FROM
  ( SELECT  @prev := '' ) AS init
JOIN
  ( SELECT  category != @prev AS first,
            @prev := category,
            category, item, ct
        FROM  ( SELECT category, item, COUNT(*) AS ct
                 FROM items1
                 GROUP BY category, item
                 ORDER BY category, item ) AS b
        ORDER BY
            category, ct DESC
  ) x
WHERE  first
ORDER BY  category  ;
```

Without a bigger dataset, it is hard to say whether runs faster or slower than Paul's solution.  And it may depend on which version of MySQL you are using.